# LiDAR rig that scans within a projection window

Tags: lidar

I had an idea for a LiDAR scanner but am having trouble locking in the feasibility of it.

First of all - I know stereo matching would be way more efficient - this is more of a thought experiment at this stage.

Usually LiDAR scanners are directed by either single or dual axis robotics, generating either a single axis scanline or a full 3D model.

What I am wondering is the feasibility of creating a LiDAR rig that scans within a 2D window, much in the same way a camera takes in light information and eventually ends up as a 2D pixel map.  The purpose of this data being for real-time recreation of an environment, requiring 30+ frames generated per second.

The data collection area would be similar to that of a stereo matching device - a field of view around the direction the unit is pointing at would get scanned.

I imagine the major data acquisition bottle neck would be the rotors the sensor is mounted on - how quickly can they traverse the acquisition window.  I believe there are LiDAR units with a high enough point collection rate for the task, but I am unsure about the robotics involved.

As an example, let's say that the task was to collect point data in a 60° x 40° window in front of the rig, with a point density of 100 x 70 and at 30 ticks per second.
7,000 points must be collected per frame to populate the region, multiplied by 30 frames per second = 210,000 points per second.  Not a huge ask for quite a few modern sensors.
Where I'm getting stumped is the best way to construct a robotics rig that will direct the sensor to the angles it needs to collect the data at, if it is even possible to move a sensor that fast.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* FacePuncher7, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: This is all hypothetical, so there's nothing firm to give feedback on here. Can a sensor do it? Most laser scanners use a spinning head to turn basically a mirror inside the scanner to choose the "firing angle" for the laser(s). You could put a prism with 72 facets, one for each vertical scan line, inside a spinning head; each facet would scan a new vertical line. You could mount a mirror to acoustic drivers tuned to the horizontal and vertical scan rates. You could have 72 lasers firing through the same head (Velodyne already does 64). You could do solid-state lidar, or fiber optic, etc.

Comment: The point is, there are lots of ways to solve a problem. It's up to you to pick a solution, but the solution that's best for *you* is specific to *your problem and your needs* and unlikely to help future visitors to the site. This is why the unbounded design questions are off-topic. Most of the robotics equipment will **not** be "commercial off-the-shelf" (COTS) solutions, but most of the lidar equipment is not COTS, either. Eye-safe lasers powerful enough to have meaningful range, not in the visible spectrum, laser detection sensors, high-speed time-of-flight chips, etc.